# How to order by a "calculated" (not MySQL function) value?

Tags: mysql

there are students and their marks:

```
Student:
ID NAME
1  a
2  b
3  c
4  d

Mark:
ID STUDENT_ID MARK
1  1          4
1  1          2
1  3          4
```

I would like to get an **ordered** list about their average marks, to get:

```
a, (4+2)/2
b, -,
c, 4/1
d, -
```

I must not calculate it while SELECT-ing, not even store it in a column in Students table. The interesting part is when I would want to order and limit (paging) the result. To have a correct ordering, I must know all averages - so I wont use SELECT query without LIMIT. But how to? Ideally, ordering by ID or NAME is easy.

Comment: You've lost me. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sounds like you need an intermediate table and pouplate it with some aggregate values.......Looks like SUM(MARK) / COUNT(StudentId).

Comment: From your constraint **I must not calculate it while SELECT-ing** this sounds like an academic exercise. It will help if you explain the point of that constraint. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @AntDC: of course, but this is what should be avoided. Its an overhead for every selecting!

Answer (score 1):

You can order by an expression, including a subquery:

```
order by (select avg(mark) from marks m where m.student_id = s.id)
```

I'm not sure I would want to do this as part of paging, unless the underlying data is pretty small.

Answer (score 1):

You can get users with their average marks with this query:

```
SELECT student.*, AVG(mark.mark) as average_mark
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN mark m on m.student_id= users.id
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY average_mark DESC
```

Comment: of course, but this is what should be avoided. Its an overhead for every selecting!

Comment: so, you can use limit and offset for pagination. you can limit the results and it would not be overhead. Please fix me up if I understand your question wrong.